# Adding a Space In Between Quotations?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

```
function mySet() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

ss.getRange("J2").setFormula("=index(split(Drive!B2," "),1,2)");

}
```

I want to be able to have a space in between these to quotes.

```
ss.getRange("J2").setFormula("=index(split(Drive!B2,' '),1,2)");
```

This seems to work using `' '` However I Need `" "` for the formula to work.

Comment: Escape the `"`'s? `ss.getRange("J2").setFormula("=index(split(Drive!B2,\" \"),1,2)");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use single quotes outside the formula:

```
ss.getRange("J2").setFormula('=index(split(Drive!B2," "),1,2)');
```

Results after running your script:

[image]